# Android Lint Check - StringFormatInvalid: what is wrong on %d%% remaining?

Tags: android, lint

I'm using Android Lint for checking my translated strings. I have a string

```
<string name='status_bar_text_remaining_capacity'>%d%% remaining</string>
```

Lint reports this

```
res/values/strings.xml:91: Error: Format string 'status_bar_text_remaining_capacity' is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to String.format [StringFormatInvalid]
<string name='status_bar_text_remaining_capacity'>%d%% remaining</string>
```

As far as I understand documentation for `String.format()` then this is valid string. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in lint which was fixed recently;
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/46741/1

The fix is in ADT 21.0.1.

Comment: i have ADT 22 , and i see this bug. i have the formatted="false" being set . should i remove it?

Comment: it's not a bug. Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

That's because you must use the [getString(int resID, Obj... args)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatar-strings) method instead of String.format().
That warning is because the getString has its own way to work with string parameters. So, every % int xml strings are special symbols to the parser telling it that there is going to have a integer informing a position. The position is represented by `1$`, `2$`, etc, and goes into the specifier (`%` and the `s`). For example

```
Captured the IMEI: %s
```

Becomoes:

```
<string name="msg_success_captured_imei">Captured the IMEI: %1$s</string>
```

If your string resource has more args, just increment the positioners:

```
<string name="msg_success_captured_imei">Captured the IMEI: %1$s %2$s %3$s</string>
```

You can use different args specifiers but must follow the sequence:

```
<string name="msg_success_captured_imei">This is a test %1$s %2$d </string>
```

Now, you just use the `getString` and pass the extra args, like:

```
getString(R.string.msg_success_captured_imei,mMyVar1, myVar2, myVar3);
```

I hope I've helped

Comment: In fact, it works, no need for the String.format part.
However, I'm still getting the same warning, I had to add a SupressLint annotation in order to get rid of it.

Comment: Yes, I have same situation still, only SupressWarning works

Answer (score -1):

Checked the same situation on the windows with lint version 21 and I got no error.

Comment: I'm using Mac with Java 7. It would be interesting to see how this check is implemented.